# Make appear a text with several clickable lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table. For certain elements, I want to make an effect such that when we mouseover (or click on) an element, a text appears next to it, and the text could have several lines and some lines can be clickable.

For example, in the table made by the following code, when we mouseover `30`, a text appears

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Points</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td><span title="monday: 10; tuesday: 10; wednesday: 10">30</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/yuletadade/1/edit?html,output)

However, I would like the appearing text to be `monday: 10`, `tuesday: 10` and `wednesday: 10` line by line. And we can click on e.g., `monday: 10` to open a page or move to another section of the page. `title` does not permit of this.

Does anyone know how to realise this? We could use JavaScript, CSS...

(* [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358874/how-can-i-use-a-carriage-return-in-a-html-tooltip) did not explain how to insert links in the appearing text *)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use a carriage return in a HTML tooltip?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358874/how-can-i-use-a-carriage-return-in-a-html-tooltip)

Comment: Well, that thread did not answer how to insert links in the appearing text...

Comment: the title property accepts  a raw string of text..It is not possible to insert html into it...You might be better off creating a tooltip ...see this http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

Comment: for links in tooltips - you'll have to work a bit harder :-) see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231315/jquery-ui-tooltip-html-with-links

Comment: hmm...would you prefer a custom made tooltip as a solution?..(Just a thought)

Comment: I did not know tooltips before, so I can make it from these examples, thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try tooltips with links

See the JQuery Example

```
https://codepen.io/jamilhijjawi/pen/lIwbK
```

You can try simple tooltips like below  with links

```
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that combines some of the aspects of [`mshameer`'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40518935/7016732) with your provided [bin](https://jsbin.com/yuletadade/1/edit?html,output).

[Solution JSBin](http://jsbin.com/huhuvudato/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

This script has two methods of creating a tooltip. The first can be declared in an HTML attribute with the `|` character serving as a line delimiter, and the second allows directly passing the element and its tooltip as a JQuery object. This means that if you don't need any specific click styling, you don't have to leave your HTML-declaration dreams behind.

**HTML:**

```
<h1 data-over="You have hovered|Over this">Here is a title</h1> 

<p id="test">TEST</p>
```

**JavaScript for searching by the `data-over` attribute:**

```
// Search for text if it's simple in the HTML
var $dataElements = $("[data-over]");
$dataElements.each(function (index, el) {
  var $el = $(el);
  var text = $el.attr("data-over");
  if (text) {
    // Split by "|"
    text = text.split("|");
    createDataOver($el, text);
  }
});
```

**JavaScript for manually adding a tooltip:**

```
// Or provide it yourself.
var $testData = $(document.createElement("span"));
$testData.text("Click me.").click(function () {
  alert("Clicked");
});
createDataOver($("#test"), $testData);
```

The `createDataOver` does the real work:

```
function createDataOver($el, data) {
  var $holder = $(document.createElement("div"));
  $holder.addClass("over hidden");

  // Check if we provided JQuery or a string array
  if (data instanceof jQuery) {
    // Manually make it relatively positioned
    $el.css("position", "relative");
    data.addClass("over-line");
    $holder.append(data);
  }
  else {
    data.forEach(function (line) {
      var $line = $(document.createElement("span"));
      $line.text(line);
      $line.addClass("over-line");
      $holder.append($line);
    });
  }

  // append with the hidden class to start
  $el.append($holder);

  // Create a closure with a timeout variable
  // So it doesn't disappear immediately if
  // we don't want it to!
  (function closure() {
    var timeoutCancel = -1;
    $el.mouseenter(function () {
      if (timeoutCancel !== -1) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutCancel);
        timeoutCancel = -1;
      }
      $holder.removeClass("hidden");
    });
    $el.mouseleave(function () {
      timeoutCancel = setTimeout(function () {
        if (timeoutCancel !== -1)
          $holder.addClass("hidden");
      }, 500);
    });
  }());
}
```

#### Caveats

This solution requires the tooltip parent to be `position: relative`. It also won't have the same entry bounds as the `title` attribute - a `display: block` `h3` element will respond to the `mouseenter` across its full row. Since your provided JSBin uses a table, this may not be an issue.

I also tried to control for the timing by having a half-second timeout on the mouseleave, that way the user can mouse back over the element in that time to keep viewing it rather than losing view of it immediately.