# How to make tooltip did not disappear until the mouse on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip, zurb-foundation

i'm using the foundation zurb 6 tooltips.  I want to add the button to the tooltip but I dont know how to make it apperance until the mouse in the tooltip. Sorry for my english, but I try to explain the problem.
For example this is my tooltip:

```
<span data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" class="has-tip" data-disable-hover="false" tabindex="1" title="Fancy word for a beetle.">TOUCH HERE</span>
```

When my mouse on the **TOUCH HERE** tooltip appears and after I move the mouse out of **TOUCH HERE** tooltip disappear. I want to make next: when mouse moved into tooltip, it should not disappear until mouse moving out from tooltip too( because I want to click any button on tooltip). How can I do this? I don't find any solutions in documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right,  foundation zurb 6 haven't any possibility to do not hide it except of span clicking. You need to extend/rewrite source codes to handle it. Or you just can choose other tooltip plugin supported required behavior.

Comment: How can I rewrite it? I'm bad in javascript

Comment: Best solution for you will be using any separate tooltip plugin

Comment: Which tooltip are you recomend to user to solve my problem?

Comment: As an example - jquery ui tooltip with solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/18238005/1151741