# ToolTip lingering(do not hide) on fast mousehover in jQuery Tooltip content retrieved from database on ajax call

Tags: tooltip

I have a java script class.inside a method I am dynamically populating table content(all rows and columns).my table has 20 rows each page.
In one column I have added ui-icon-info.
on mouse hover on each icon I call a new java script method(showToolTip) that I have written.
from showToolTip method I am done ajax call to fetch a note(content for tooltip).
After ajax call it goes to another method where I am using jQuery to display tooltip.
my code is similar to below:

```
$( "#"+toolTipId ).tooltip({
content: toolTipNote(coming from ajax call),
track: true,
position: { my: "left+15 center", at: "right center" },
show: false,
hide: false,
}).
```

toolTipId is change dynamically on each mouse hover.
Now:
with above code tool tip was showing on second time mouse hover onwards on each icon  and I did not have any tooltip lingering issue.tooltip hides on mouseout.
But I need to show tooltip from first mouse hover.
I came across few solution:
put my above code inside $(function){}--did not work
put my above code inside $(document).ready(function(){})--did not work
`.tooltip('open')`--it worked

```
$( "#"+toolTipId ).tooltip({
content: toolTipNote(coming from ajax call),
track: true,
position: { my: "left+15 center", at: "right center" },
show: false,
hide: false,
}).tooltip('open')
```

but I got tooltip lingering issue.when I move mouse fast on many icons quickly.
when I tried to close tooltip.that is also not working for me.may be I m doing incorrect.

any help will be highly appriciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: below solution almost working for me:                                                     open: function(event, ui)
    {
        if (typeof(event.originalEvent) === 'undefined')
        {
            return false;
        }

        var $id = $(ui.tooltip).attr('id');

        // close any lingering tooltips
        $('div.ui-tooltip').not('#' + $id).remove();

        // ajax function to pull in data and add it to the tooltip goes here
    }.when I hover mouse on my ui-icon-info icon it closes all previous tooltip.small problem is one last tooltip is lingering for infinite time.

Comment: Any solution to this will be appreciated.                                                        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660576/only-close-tooltip-if-mouse-is-not-over-target-or-tooltip